# iPad3 Gray line issue while Split keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am new to ios development and i am facing the strange problem when we split the keyboard.

I am using custom keypad for data input in the textfield so i hide system keyboard and for that i have used the method `[textfield setInputview:label];` in that i am giving textfield inputview to label of `size(0,0,1,1)`.

Now when there is splitkeyboard then there is a gray line in bottom! And when there is normal keyboard(Without Split) then there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I remember that apple sent me an info about an ios 6.1 beta 2 pre update, that solves this. You should have received that email, too. (Apple Developper)

Answer (score 0):

Try using (0, 0, 0, 0) size for your `inputView` label, this worked fine for me (in my case I used `UIView` with (0, 0, 0, 0) size as `inputView` to fix this problem).